# SQL query - not null

Tags: sql, impala

I have sql query:

```
Select id
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "10") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position10
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "18") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position18
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "20") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position20
    
FROM table
WHERE 
date BETWEEN "${od=2021-05-01 00:00:01}" AND "${do=2021-07-01 00:00:01}"
AND pos IN('10','18','20')
group by id
```

I got this table

| id | position10 | position20 | position30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-02 | 2021-05-02 | 2021-05-3 |
| 2 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-05-16 | 2021-05-18 |
| 3 | 2021-07-08 | NULL | NULL |

And I want lines where NULL values are not picked up.
A try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
Select id
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "10") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position10
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "18") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position18
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "20") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position20
        
    FROM table
    WHERE 
    date BETWEEN "${od=2021-05-01 00:00:01}" AND "${do=2021-07-01 00:00:01}"
    AND pos IN('10','18','20')
    group by id )T 
WHERE (position10 IS NOT NULL)
       OR (position18 IS NOT NULL)
       OR (position20 IS NOT NULL)
```

But it still chooses to me where the NULL value appears somewhere.

Comment: WHERE (position10 IS NOT NULL)
       AND(position18 IS NOT NULL)
       AND(position20 IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Replace OR with AND?

Comment: OMG I am stupid :D I didn't even give me the problem here. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `OR` to `AND` in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM (
Select id
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "10") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position10
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "18") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position18
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN (pos = "20") THEN date ELSE NULL END) position20
        
    FROM table
    WHERE 
    date BETWEEN "${od=2021-05-01 00:00:01}" AND "${do=2021-07-01 00:00:01}"
    AND pos IN('10','18','20')
    group by id )T 
WHERE position10 IS NOT NULL
       AND position18 IS NOT NULL
       AND position20 IS NOT NULL
```